# Need to categorize Data from json

Tags: json, flutter, listview

I am reading json data that Contain some items (and Items have some categories I wanna show data on the basis of categories like using same widget again and again just have to change category name only Here What I have done so far it show all the items.
Also Added image for items.

```
Widget buildItems(List<[![Items]> items) => GridView.builder(
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
      mainAxisExtent: 170,
    ),
    //itemCount: items.length,
    itemCount: itemCount,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final item = items[index];
      int random = Random().nextInt(items.length);
      print(random);

      return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    DetailScreen(item: item))),
            // => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            //       builder: (BuildContext context) =>
            //          ProductPage(product: product))),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  boxShadow: const [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black38,
                        // spreadRadius: 5,
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: Offset(0, 5.0)),
                    BoxShadow(color: Colors.white, offset: Offset(-1, 0)),
                    BoxShadow(color: Colors.white, offset: Offset(2, 0)),
                  ]),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                      child: Image.network(
                        '$imageLink${item.imageUrl}',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 110,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              margin:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 10),
                              height: 40,
                              width: 40,
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                  child: Image.network(
                                      '$iconLink${item.logo}',
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                            ),
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 120,

                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 7, left: 5),
                                    child: Flexible(
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        child: Text('${item.name}',
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .bodyText1),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    // Flexible(
                                    //   child: Text(
                                    //     product.name,
                                    //     style: const TextStyle(
                                    //         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    //         color: Colors.black,
                                    //         fontSize: 14),
                                    //   ),
                                    // ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 2,
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                                  child: Text('${item.subcategory}',
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .bodyText2!
                                          .copyWith(
                                              color: kButtonBackground)),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
          // ListTile(
          //   onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          //       builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          //           ProductPage(product: product))),
          //   title: Text(product.name),
          // ),
          );
    },
  );
```

//------------------------------ JSON SAMPLE

```
[ {
      "name": "Item1",
      "category": "Apple",
      "subcategory": "Productivity",
      "imageUrl": "Banner.jpg",
      "logo": "logo.png",
      "description": "falkr."
    },
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "category": "Testing1",
      "subcategory": "Productivity",
      "imageUrl": "banner.jpg",
      "logo": "System.png",
      "description": "Testing."
    }
]
```

//-------------------------------

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX9Hh.png

Comment: and what's your question that  you need an answer for, do you want to get multiple lists based on category or you want to a way to implement them to widgets ?

Comment: Both Wanna get list based on specific category like If I select category apple it should only display that.

Answer (score 0):

@Talal, you have to filter the list based on the selected category, like below

```
List<Items> categorySpecificItems = allItems.where((item) => item.category == selectedCategory).toList()
```

Now pass the categorySpecificItems to buildItems on the change of selected category and use some state handling to render the UI.

Hope this works!

Comment: In the code above can you modify bit where I can place this part

Comment: You have to write this code in itemBuilder before return statement.

Comment: Haven't got that